# Is AngularJS controller performance impacted by having many $scope declarations as opposed to a nested $scope object?

Tags: angularjs

`$scope.foo = { a1 : '1', a2 : '2' ... aN : 'n' }`

versus

`$scope.a1 = '1'; $scope.a2 = '2'; ... $scope.aN = 'n';`

Is there a performance hit in having many single `$scope.varName` declarations when they could be bundled into one object and one $scope declaration? The reason I ask is I have inherited an angular code base with serious performance issues. The controllers are massive, 100 - 150 $scope declarations, some of which should have been rolled into one nested object. Just looking for some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: The title you have chosen for your post is a very unhelpful one. The title is meant to summarize the post, not reproduce it.

Comment: you mean in milliseconds, who care ?

Comment: I see the main difference as the first making sense, while the second being pain to write and looking ugly. Speed difference will be minimal if any.

Comment: There's no safe answer to this. Different browsers can act differently and implement its javascript engine differently. This is in its current form too broad to answer.

Comment: I am asking in terms of the logic contained within the AngularJS framework, not in different browsers, I believe there is a safe answer. Each $scope declaration binds data. How are $scope declarations iterated over during a $digest? Are there notable startup cost associated with each $scope declaration when a $digest occurs that could be avoided with a nested object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance should only be a concern when profiling shows that the particular code is a bottleneck. Until then use the most appropriate solution for the problem.

Don't make an application harder to read and maintain to solve a non-existent performance issue.

Use a nested object when appropriate for the properties that belong together. Use separate declarations for unrelated data.